# multi form multi model in ASP MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hello everybody,

I am trying to learn C# ASP MVC and I have a little problem.

I want to release a simple blog.

So I want on the same page to display an article and a form to comment the post.

I have a model for the post and another for the comment.

***This is my model :***

**comment.cs**

```cs
public class Comment
        {
            public Guid id { get; set; }
            public string content { get; set; }
            public int numComment { get; set; }
            public virtual Post postId { get; set; }
            public virtual ApplicationUser author { get; set; }
        }
```

**post.cs**

```cs
public class Post
    {
        public Guid id { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string content { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> author { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Comment> comments { get; set; }
    }
```

I use the post model to show the details of an article so I can't use the comment model to register a comment.

What is the best practice ? I have seen about @html.action and partial view or complex viewModel with the post and comment model in a same class.

Thank you very much for all clues you give it to me.

*Sorry for the English mistakes, I am french.

Comment: Don't use data models in your view - use view models. Then the view model will contain a properties for the post and the new comment. Alternatively, you can also use `@Html.Action()` to call a method which returns a partial view of a `CommentViewModel` (passing the Post's `Id` value)

Comment: Thank you for your help. It's a good idea. Do you have some example code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a very basic example which has page displaying the article.

1. The page uses a partial view to retrieve a list of comments
2. The page uses AJAX to insert a new comment
3. If the comment was inserted successfully we call the partial view in step 1 to refresh the list of comments.

Everything happens on one page, thanks to jQuery and AJAX:

**Code first data objects:**

```
public class Comment
{
    public Guid id { get; set; }
    public string content { get; set; }
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.ForeignKey("post")]
    public Guid? PostId { get; set; }
    public int numComment { get; set; }
    public virtual Post post { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser author { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public Guid id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string content { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> author { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> comments { get; set; }
}

public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DatabaseContext() : base("name=Connection")
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
}
```

**MVC controller:**

```
public class NewsController : Controller
{
    private DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Post firstPost = db.Posts.FirstOrDefault();
        return View(firstPost);
    }

    public PartialViewResult GetComments(string postId)
    {
        Guid post = Guid.Parse(postId);
        List<Comment> comments = db.Comments.Where(c => c.PostId == post).ToList();
        return PartialView("~/Views/News/_Comments.cshtml", comments);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AddComment(string postId,string content)
    {
        Guid post = Guid.Parse(postId);

        var comment = new Comment
        {
            id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            PostId = post,
            content = content
        };

        db.Comments.Add(comment);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return Json(new {Created = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

**Partial view for comments(called _Comments.cshtml):**

```
@model List<Newspaper.Models.Comment>

@foreach(var comment in Model)
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 well">@comment.content</div>
    </div>
}
```

**Main view:**

```
@model Newspaper.Models.Post

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        GetCommentsForArticle();

        function GetCommentsForArticle() {
            debugger;
            var id = '@Model.id';
            $.get("/News/GetComments?postId=" + id, function (data) {
                $("#comments").empty();
                $("#comments").append(data);
            });
        }

        $("#btnPostComment").click(function () {
            var id = '@Model.id';
            var comment = $("#comment").val();

            $.ajax({
                url: "/News/AddComment",
                type: "Post",
                data: { 'postId': id , 'content':comment},
                success: function (data) {
                    debugger;
                    GetCommentsForArticle();
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    alert('An error occured while posting a comment');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12"><h1>Article - @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.title) </h1></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.content)</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="comments" class="container">
</div>
<div class="container">
    <h3>Add another comment</h3>
    Comment<input type="text" id="comment" />
    <input type="button" id="btnPostComment" value="Post Comment" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this complete detail example

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Comment
{
     public Guid id { get; set; }
     public string content { get; set; }
     public int numComment { get; set; }
     public virtual Post postId { get; set; }
     public virtual ApplicationUser author { get; set; }
 }

public class Post
{
     public Guid id { get; set; }
     public string title { get; set; }
     public string content { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> author { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<Comment> comments { get; set; }
     public Comment Commentobject {get;set;}
 }
```

And Use view model concept.Declare post model in the view using @model keyword.Get the values on form post in controller